# Reproducir audio en JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, audio

En mi HTML tengo puesto lo siguiente (ademas del "display:none" en el css):

```
<audio class="audio">
    <source src="~/Audios/NUMEROS/ONE.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Y para ejectutar dicho Audio, pongo el siguiente codigo en mi archivo javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".audio").play();
});
```

Pero cuando abro la pagina, en consola me sale el siguiente error:

**Uncaught TypeError: audio.play is not a function**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ejecutar el audio tienes que especificar su posición en el array de elementos que has seleccionando con jQuery. En este caso seria de tal forma:

`$(".audio")[0].play();`

Hay que hacerlo de esta manera porqué el equipo de jQuery decidió no añadir la función `play()` a todos los elementos, ya que solo afecta a los de `audio`.

Aquí esta el razonamiento oficial (en inglés): https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10374