# Reproducir audios en JQuery mediante clases

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones, audio

estoy creando una página para aprender japonés, y me han sugerido el incluir audios de cada kanji, con lo que he intentado crear una función que sea dinámica y que si **clicas el botón** con esa clase, **se reproduzca el audio**. Éste es el código que he creado, pero no me funciona, y no entiendo qué puede estar fallando:

```
<button class="audio-btn">Reproducir</button>
<audio class="audio">
  <source src="http://audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>

<script>
  $(".audio-btn").click(function () {
    $(".audio").play();
  });
</script>
```

Si alguien me puede dar alguna pista, ¡gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuál es la URL real del audio? Seguramente sea porque no te está cargando el fichero

Comment: Puedes las respuestas a este post, creo que te servirá [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168216/reproducir-audio-en-jquery]

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que JQuery no tiene una función de play. Así que cuando seleccionas el elemento `$(".audio").play();` en realidad estas llamando la funcion play, pero del selector JQuery y no del elemento DOM.

Para que te funcione simplemente debes recuperar el elemento DOM luego de seleccionarlo con JQuery agregando el metodo **get()** asi: `$(".audio").get(0).play();`

Comment: Entiendo que entonces los datos de los kanjis tengo que meterlos obligatoriamente mediante un **for** para que coja el id del Array, y que no sirve tenerlos de forma manual, ¿no? Era lo que quería evitar porque sino tendré que editar toda la información de nuevo, y ni aún así me quedará igual. Por eso me interesaba usar una clase en vez de un id.